# Where can I find information on recently implemented features on Trello?

Tags: trello

I have a question regarding [Trello](http://trello.com/).

Before its release, Trello used to have a page showing the release notes. I dug around and found out [its location](http://trello.com/notes). But it's dated, it even mentions the old name Trellis, and [the "manual"](http://trello.com/about) has no pointer to it, so I guess it shouldn't be used.

So... Where can I find the release notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information on recently release bug fixes and features on the [Trello development board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).  We leave things in the "Implemented" column for a while after they go live.

Comment: The release notes were much more useful imho.  Everything I learned about Trello came from reading it from the beginning.  Would never have known about @reply or due dates otherwise to name a couple.  Definitely missing it and wondering what features I'm missing out on.  (Though I know how much of a pain a [release log](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/140548) can be.)